# Why does the the function not work when the parameter is a pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers, enums, malloc

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


typedef enum lightSwitch {
        OFF = 0,
        ON
}lightSwitch;

void setLight(lightSwitch setting){
        if(setting == 1){
                printf("(v)\n =\n");
        }
}
int main(void){

  char *p = malloc(sizeof(lightSwitch));
  printf("'ON' or 'OFF'?\n");
  scanf("%s", p);
  setLight(*p);

}
```

I am not completely sure what is wrong with this code. When the user inputs "OFF" then the light bulb is supposed stay hidden, but if the user inputs "ON" then the lightbulb is supposed to be shown.

Comment: an enum is not a string

Comment: Aside, did you mean `if(setting == ON)`? You aren't using the `enum` values you defined.

Comment: `*p` is the first character of the string from the user, likely 'O'

Comment: An enum is a just a "mask" or "map" or whatever word you want to use for an integer, in this case not much different than `#define OFF 0` and `#define ON 1`. Your code seems to imply that you believe that an enum maps a string to a value, as though the string "OFF" resolves to 0, if that's what you are thinking you're understanding of enums is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `char *p = malloc(sizeof(lightSwitch));`, you need to take note of two things:

1. Make sure to `free(p)` when you don't need it anymore. (Although not required in this case as the program will free it automatically for you after termination, but still, you should do it as it considered good practice.)
2. `sizeof (lightSwitch)` is essentially just writing `sizeof (int)` which is platform-dependent, so the size of your string may vary in different platforms and might probably lead to undefined behavior which is never desirable.

```c
/* The below two lines shouldn't be used unless you have put both 'stdio.h'
   and 'stdlib.h' inside your program's source directory, which isn't really a sane idea */
// #include "stdio.h"
// #include "stdlib.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum lightSwitch {
    OFF,
    ON
} lightSwitch;

void setLight(lightSwitch setting) {
    if(setting == ON)
        printf("(v)\n =\n");
}

int main(void) {
    // It suffices to simply use an array instead of a dynamically allocated pointer in this context
    char p[4] = {0};

    printf("'ON' or 'OFF'?\n");
    scanf("%3s", p);

    // strcmp(a, b) essentially compares the equality of two strings passed to it and returns 0 if they are equal
    setLight(strcmp(p, "ON") == 0 ? ON : OFF);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to ask malloc for memory and you pass it the size of the enum, your should pass it the sizeof(char) * number of characters you want the string to be (Note that you need to leave one byte for [terminating the string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-a-null-terminated-string-in-c-cplusplus)).

Second, you're trying to to compare between a char* and an integer.

What you should be doing is something like this :

```
if(strcmp(p,"ON") == 0) 
 setLight(ON); //use the enum attribute
else
 setLight(OFF);
```

Check the input string and then pass the corresponding enum value you want to the setLight function.

Comment: Code like `if(*p == "ON")` ain't never gonna work. How would a `char` (`*p`) equal a string (`"ON"`)?

Answer (score 0):

An enum isn't a string. OFF is just another way of writing 0. And ON is just another way of writing 1. They have nothing to do with the strings "ON" or "OFF". When your program is compiled, the compiler doesn't put the names "ON" or "OFF" into the program, so the program has no idea what they are called.

So with that in mind, your program is allocating some memory, reading a string into that memory (i.e. suppose the user typed ON, then byte 0 becomes 'O', byte 1 becomes 'N', byte 3 becomes 0), then checking whether the first byte is equal to 1, which it isn't, because the ASCII code for 'O' is 79.

Answer (score 0):

The enumeration constant `ON` is a completely different animal from the string `"ON"` and they have absolutely no connection to each other.  You can't enter the name of a variable or a constant as a string and be able to access the corresponding value - C just doesn't work that way.

You are going to have to find a way to manually map the strings `"ON"` and `"OFF"` the the corresponding enumeration values (or forego using enumerations and just use strings).

To read the string you need a buffer large enough to hold all the characters of the string plus the string terminator.  There’s absolutely no need to muck with dynamic memory in this case<sup>1</sup> - you just need to allocate a fixed-length array of `char`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHARACTERS 3 // length of "OFF"

int main(void){

  char buf[MAX_CHARACTERS+1] = {0}; // +1 to allow for the string terminator

  printf("'ON' or 'OFF'?\n");

  /**
   * We're going to use fgets instead of scanf - it's easier to
   * protect against buffer overflow.  
   */
  if ( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin ) ) 
  {                                      
    /**
     * First, make sure the input string is all upper case - that way 
     * we don't have to worry about comparing against "on", "On", "oN",
     * etc.
     */
    for ( char *p = buf; *p != 0; p++ )
      *p = toupper( *p );

    /**
     * Create a variable of type lightSwitch - this is what we'll
     * pass to setLight.  Default value is OFF
     */
    lightSwitch setting = OFF; 

    if ( strcmp( buf, "ON" ) == 0 )
      setting = ON;

    setLight( setting );        
  }
  else
  {
    // handle input error here
  }
}
```

As written, this will only enable the light if the user types `"ON"`; for any other input the light will be off.  If you don't want to create a separate variable, we could also write it:

```
if ( strcmp( buf, "ON" ) )
  setLight( ON );
else
  setLight( OFF );
```

which would do the same thing.

---

1. `sizeof (lightSwitch)` returns the size of a `lightSwitch` object (which could be as few as 2 bytes), not the number of characters required to hold the strings `"ON"` or `"OFF"`; when allocating space to store a string, you need to allocate space for N characters plus the string terminator.  A better option would have been to use `strlen( "OFF" ) + 1` as the argument to `malloc`, but again in this case you don't need to use dynamic memory.